# Trying to unembed a SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query below which runs fine and returns the expeceted results

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @columns = N'';


SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME([Name])
FROM
  (SELECT [Description] AS [Name]
   FROM CNF_PaymentMethod AS p
   WHERE Enabled = 1
     AND PaymentMethodId <> 17
   GROUP BY [Description]) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT [TransactionId], '+STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '')+' FROM (
SELECT [TransactionId], [PaymentAmount] AS [Value],  [Description] as [Name] 
    FROM [CNF_PaymentMethod]
    join [DATA_Payment]
    on [CNF_PaymentMethod].[PaymentMethodId] = [DATA_Payment].[PaymentMethodId]
    ) AS j PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR [Name] in 
      
      ('+(STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, ''))+')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I want to unembed the SET @sql statement so I can run it unembedded but I can't seem to get the format of this right

```
('+(STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, ''))+')) AS p;';
```

I end up with an expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID error

Comment: What does unembedded mean here? And which version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 1):

This is what's called a Dynamic SQL statement.  The point of the `SET @sql...` is to dynamically generate a SQL statement based on a set of variables.  In this case, the variable bit is the results of the `SELECT` above the `SET`.  If you change the `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` to `PRINT @sql` you'll see the statement that is generated.

Be aware that the SQL statement will likely be different every time you run this script based on the values within `CNF_PaymentMethod`.  You could create a view from the generated SQL statement that the `PRINT` would output, but that would only be a one-time snapshot.  There really isn't much value in creating a view out of this.